# Docker Container Containing Multiple Services

Tags: docker, nginx, architecture, grafana, node-red

I am trying to build a container containing 3 applications, for example:

- Grafana;
- Node-RED;
- NGINX.

So I will just need to expose one por, for example:

NGINX reverse proxy on port 3001/grafana redirects to grafana on port 3000 and;
NGINX reverse proxy on port 3001/nodered redirects to nodered on port 1880.

Does it make any sense in your vision? Or this architecture is not feasible if compared to docker compose?

[image]

Comment: Use Docker-compose, it's what it's for.

Comment: You can run containers without publishing their ports.  But running multiple programs in a single container isn't usually a best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your concern is about opening only one port publicly.

For this, you would be better off building 3 separate containers, each with their own service, and **all in the same docker network**. You could plug your services like you described within the virtual network instead of within the same container.

Why ? Because containers are specifically designed to hold the environment for a single application, in order to provide isolation and reduce compatibility issues, with all the network configuration done at a higher level, outside of the containers.

Having all your services inside the same container thwart these mentioned advantages of containerized applications. It's almost like you're not even using containers.

Comment: Thank you @adamency, it makes lot of sense.